# VS Code Output result different from Terminal result

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I just started learning python about a week ago and I am using VS code.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ClassMarks.csv')
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 85)

df['Final Marks'] = df['CPQ']+df['HW']+df['Tutorials']+df['Tests']
print(df)
```

in the Output terminal it gives:

```
File "/Users/User1/Desktop/test", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

while the Terminal gives me the result table I expect, with no errors.

Does anyone knows what is happening or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

The problem I had was, that my Output window was using python 2.7.16 as default. To change it to python 3.8.2, I found the answer in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06I63_p-2A4,
starting from min 43:00.

I hope this helps others!

Comment: Check if pandas is visible to python in the output terminal

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: it is ok to post your own solution and accept it. An accepted solution is easier found by users used to stack overflow.

Comment: @nuiun Thank you, I didn't know I can do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had was, that my Output window was using python 2.7.16 as default. To change it to python 3.8.2, I found the answer in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06I63_p-2A4, starting from min 43:00.

I hope this helps others!